# What is the best way to store historical stock data in 1-min intervals?

Tags: linux, database-design

I need to build a system to store the following data:

1. 10,000 stocks
2. For each stock, I should keep data for 1000 fields ("open", "high", .....)
3. Each field gets updated 390 times in a day (meaning, there are 390 intervals)
4. Overall, I have a total of 10 years of data for each stock/field/interval

Here are the requirements in terms of insertion/querying:

1. Fast inserts of data as it comes in
2. Retrievals would normally be as follows: `give me all stocks for field 'X' on interval 'Y'`. such a query must be retrieved as fast as possible

In terms of budget, since I do not have the means to buy a huge server and something like SQL-SERVER to store the data, a friend recommended that I look into MySQL. I tried it, but queries are extremely slow if I don't add any indices to the table. On the other hand, if I do add indices, the insertions are tremendously slow, so this does not help either.
My machine has only 2GB of memory in it, so either way, the indices will not fit in memory.

What is the best way to store such data in a scalable way (I might have even more fields as time goes by...)? is it true that flat binary files, on a by field/by interval basis, are the best solution given my requirements and budget?

(If it makes any difference at all, I use Linux)

Comment: So even if each of those fields was only 1 byte you are looking at almost 4GB a day and you have 10 *years* of data?  I don't think you are going to be running this on your laptop.

Comment: @Duck: I have multiple machines, each with 2 1.5TB hard drives. The key in this question is: what is the best way to store the data, assuming no joins / concurrent read/write is needed.

Comment: I understand and better db people than I will no doubt help but you have piqued my curiosity.  At a minimum, if I have the calcs right, you are looking at 10TB.  I am perplexed by the 1000 fields part.  If it is just 1 minute price/volume data, even from a dozen different exchanges, why so many fields?

Comment: @user540009, can you explain the need for 1,000 columns? It smells like design flaw, but you'd have to tell us more.

Comment: @Duck / @Ronnis: every stock has up to 1000 fields of data. I'm talking about 'grain' data, that cannot be calculated from price/volume.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

MySQL is probably not what you want if you're dealing with data you need represented faithfully and with powerful indexing.  I'd suggest PostgreSQL, which is also free and generally an all-around great project(TM).

Flat binary files (or even ASCII) should be a decent solution **if you don't need to manipulate the data in place afterward or do complicated joins.**  If you're going to have to edit data in its current location in the flatfile, you have an enormous chore.  If you need to add fields later with a flat file, you have a bigger chore.

PostgreSQL handles indexing reasonably, and caches queries for performance.  Indexing shouldn't pose too much of a challenge if you tune your system for the quantity of RAM you're dealing with.

I'd suggest that you avoid flatfiles for your needs, and if queries are still too slow even with a properly tuned RDBMS instance that you find a way to shrink the amount of data that needs to be processed.  Keeping each year of data in a separate table is a simplistic but easy method for doing this, and searching the whole database can still be easily accomplished with joins.

---

Edit: Another neat thing you can do is partition your data table.  This has all kinds of benefits, like letting you move data that needs to be accessed in parallel to separate drives or (again) put individual spans of time in different places.  More information:

http://www.postgresql.org/docs/8.2/static/ddl-partitioning.html

---

Edit: For more on why I'd suggest avoiding MySQL, let me direct you here: http://code.openark.org/blog/mysql/but-i-do-want-mysql-to-say-error

Comment: @Kerin: is `PostgreSQL` in the same league as SQL-SERVER?  also, are you sure `Indexing shouldn't pose too much of a challenge if you tune your system for the quantity of RAM you're dealing with`? will I get reasonable performance with say 2GB - 4GB memory given the size of the DB?

Comment: @User, that's a matter of much debate - OSS versus Microsoft discussions turn into firestorms for a reason.  But I'd argue that yes, Postgres is very much in the same league - it's in use by  MySpace, Yahoo! (albeit a heavily modified version), and several government agencies.  Skype uses it for their central business databases as well.   As for performance on your hardware, well - it's definitely not going to be as fast as flatfile.  But with proper care, it will deliver excellent performance for the hardware.  It is necessary to keep in mind what is realistic given your system.

Comment: You can also eke a lot of performance out of something like memcached to speed frequent queries, and if slow inserts become a problem even with reasonable indexing choices you can set up one of your multiple machines to handle reads and another to handle all the writes.

Comment: Kerin: given the need to configure everything, why is it then better than flat files (given the fact that there are no concurrent reads/writes, no need for joins etc)?

Comment: If you don't need those features, it isn't better.  But there are a couple things to consider, like that splitting the workload between multiple machines will need a custom solution without a database.  Changing the number of columns later is still going to suck.  And if you want to get good read/lookup performance out of a many-gig file, you're going to need to write something to analyze the request and start looking intelligently, so it doesn't need to thrash the whole thing through RAM on each report.

Comment: By all means, a flatfile CAN perform better - but the risk of redeveloping the modern database (or a subset thereof) without the decades of testing, bugfixes and optimization.

Comment: @User, you could also look into something like MongoDB or CouchDB (both free and open source, if I recall correctly) which are optimized for large data stores where the "relational" part of "relational database" isn't required.  They're niche solutions, though, so asking in a new question would probably be best.

Comment: @Kerin: thank you. I tend to go towards multiple binary files, in a custom format; this appears to give the best scalability in such a case (and will not require a server with 10s of GB of RAM). Am I right on this?

Comment: @User, no problem.  If you're willing to put in the extra work and take on the added risk, then it'll probably serve your purposes.  That solution sounds a lot like MongoDB's implementation which splits the database into 2GB files.

Comment: @User, It's no problem, best of luck.